# process loop in C

Tags: c, process

I'm trying to write a code about a process that executes programs from $PATH using the execlp() command.(it doesn't need to be the execlp command but I've found it useful for this one) I've achieved my expected output, but I need to run more than one commands. More specifically I want the child process to run the exec command, then the parent process to print a text indicating that it's ready to accept another command. Then the child process will run the new exec command. My code is this:

```
int main ( int argc, char *argp[]) { 
pid_t progpid = fork(); // the fork command for the creation of the child process
int status = 0;
char com[256];

if (progpid < 0)  // the check in case of failure
   {
    printf("PROGRAM ABORTED!");
    return 0;
   }
do
   {
    if (progpid == 0)  // the child process
      {
       scanf( "%s", com);
         if (com == "exit")
          {
            exit(0);
          }
        else
            {
               execlp(com, com, NULL);
            }
      }
else //the parent process
    {
      wait(&status);
      printf("$");
    }
}while (com != "exit");
return 0;
}
```

The expected output is :

```
<program which I input from keyboard> ( for example  : ls )
<output of the program>
$<next program>
<output of the next program>
.
.
.
$exit
```

In short I want to keep running programs till I enter exit where it ends without doing anything else. However the output I get is this:

```
<program>
<output of program>
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
```

It keeps printing $ until I shut it down. I'm new to processes so please don't be too harsh about my code so far.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The logic of your loop is flawed. You only create *one* child process, at the beginning of the program. You need to create one child process *per command entered*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
if (com == "exit")
```

should be

```
if (strcmp(com, "exit") == 0)
```

Similarly change the `while` condition as well.

In C, *string* comparisons are done using `strcmp()`. `==` in your case, simply compares the address  of `com` and the address of the string literal `"exit"`. (In expressions, an array gets converted into a pointer to its first element. Hence, "address" comparison. Also see: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)).

Note that your `execlp()` call has an issue. NULL may be defined as 0, in which case `execlp()`, being a variadic function, may be able to recognize it as the last argument.
I'd suggest to change it to:

```
execlp(com, com, (char*)0);
```

You'd also want to check if `wait()` failed or not by checking its return code.

---

Here's a simple example based on yours with improved error checking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argp[]) {

for(;;) {
    char com[1024];
    printf("$ ");
    fgets(com, sizeof com, stdin);
    com[strcspn(com, "\n")] = 0; /* Remove if there's a newline at the end */

    if (strcmp(com, "exit") == 0) {
       exit(0);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
       execlp(com, com, (char*)0);
    }

    int status;
    int rc = wait(&status);
    /* You can inspect 'status' for further info. */
    if (rc == -1) {
        perror("wait");
        exit(1);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Note that if you want your to execute commands with arguments then you need to do argument processing.

Comment: wait did not fail. I have tested it without the do while loop and it works.

Comment: I am just saying it'd be a good practice to check the return code. If there's any problem with the execution `com` then you'd want to know about it.